# React Toggle on map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here i have an **onClick** in map function, if i click **onClick** it will effect all the input text, how to do it only for particular ID

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {Edit: false};    
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

  handleClick(){
    this.setState(state => ({
      EDIT: !state.EDIT
    }));
  }
......................

<ul>
 {data.map(item=>
  <div key={item._id}>
  <li>{item.name}</li>
  <li>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>edit</button
        {this.state.EDIT ?
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <input type="text"/>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        : item.color
      }
  </li>
  </div>
 )}
</ul>
```

Comment: I would recommend creating a new component that handles its own form, state and click handling. Then your map can simply return a new instance of that component. This is also more modular and follows React best practices better.

Comment: Hi Harry, please see my solution below and let me know if that helps :)

Comment: sure dear Chris Ngo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a anonymous function as your event-handler, and through that, call `handleClick`, passing it the id of the item to edit.

However, that is not enough to conditionally display the form. Instead of having `this.state.Edit` simply be a `true` or `false` value. You should have it record the id of the currently selected item instead.

### Event-handler

```
  handleClick(id){
    this.setState({
      EDIT: id
    })
  }
```

### Map

```
<ul>
 {data.map(item=>
  <div key={item._id}>
  <li>{item.name}</li>
  <li>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(item._id)}>edit</button>
        {this.state.EDIT == item._id ?
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <input type="text"/>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        : item.color
      }
  </li>
  </div>
 )}
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you will have to make some updates to your code to get the updating/saving-functionality to work as expected.

See sandbox for working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-johnson-ploqb

Comment: Its working well, thanks for your valuable answer :)

Comment: @HarryEdward you're very welcome friend. I'm glad that this was helpful to you!

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the id as argument to event handler

```
  handleClick(id){
    this.setState(state => ({
      [`EDIT_${id}`]: true
    }));
  }
......................

<ul>
 {data.map(item=>
  <div key={item._id}>
  <li>{item.name}</li>
  <li>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(item._id)}>edit</button
        {this.state[`EDIT_${item._id}`] ?
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <input type="text"/>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        : item.color
      }
  </li>
  </div>
 )}
</ul>
```

Comment: Its working well, thanks for your valuable answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the `id` to `handleClick` function, also to make form visible for specific `id` only you need another condition like `this.state.activeID === item._id && this.state.EDIT`,

```
<ul>
 {data.map(item=>
  <div key={item._id}>
  <li>{item.name}</li>
  <li>
        <button onClick={()=>this.handleClick(item._id)}>edit</button>
        {this.state.activeID === item._id && this.state.EDIT ? //This will confirm specific `item._id` form will get visible
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <input type="text"/>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        : item.color
      }
  </li>
  </div>
 )}
</ul>
```

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       Edit: false,
       activeID:'' //new state variable
    };    
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

  handleClick(id){
    this.setState(state => ({
      EDIT: !state.EDIT,
      activeID: id
    }));
  }
```

---

**Update**

You may avoid use of `EDIT` state variable, but in case you need to show toggle effect, you can make use of `EDIT` like,

```
<button onClick={()=>this.handleClick(item._id)}>{!this.state.EDIT ? 'Show Form' : 'Hide Form'}</button>
```

In this case on the click of button you can show/hide the form.

Comment: Its working well, thanks for your valuable answer :)